# What exactly happens within the dynamically generated byte code of a Dynamic Proxy?

Tags: java, jax-ws

Using VisualVM as profiler we are observing a high CPU utilazation within a Dynamic Proxy class created be the JAX-WS runtime with `java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance`. This CPU utilazation is not within the InvocationHandler, that does the "real work", but really in the proxy class (`com.sun.proxy.Proxy$123.myMethod()`). Eventually this results in a unduly high CPU load on the server the code is running on.

My naive understanding would be that the Dynamic Proxy just has to wrap parameters into an object array and pass that to the InvocationHandler that it has been constructed with and return the result. As this could hardly cause a high CPU load, I would be interested in what the Dynamic Proxy maybe does additionally. Some kind of possibly expensive security checks maybe?

Comment: It uses reflection, which is orders of magnitude less efficient than direct method calls. Why are you using a dynamic proxy in the first place?

Comment: We use JAX-WS as a client for a Soap webservice. Internally JAX-WS uses dynamic proxies. As to the reflection overhead, to my understanding only a Method reference has to be created and passed to the InvocationHandler by the proxy. This reference can be created when the proxy is constructed so that no reflection code is needed to handle the method invocations.

Comment: Calling the Method is reflective.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see where reflection should happen here. The client calls the Method myMethod() of the generated Proxy. This is a normal method call. The Proxy then calls InvocationHandler.invoke() - another normal method call -  passing <code>this</code>, a reflective Method reference to <code>com.sun.proxy.Proxy$123.myMethod</code> and an Object-Array with the arguments. I think there is no reflective method call involved.